# How can one display a 1km by 1km wide map using Leaflet maps?P

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I would like to display a map that is square and corresponds to a geographical area of 1km by 1km using Leaflet maps js. 
Let's say I have an Html div element of 100px by 100px, how can I achieve displaying the 1km x 1km? The only functions available in the Leaflet library are setZoomLevel and fitBounds. 
Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Calculate the bounds...

Comment: Adding a sketch of what you are trying to achieve would surely help. Also make sure you need an interactive map (100x100px is rather small). A static map is much simpler to achieve.